# What is the simplest way to display a NSString value?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, nsstring

I'm trying to display a variable value to the IPhone screen. I'm using XCode and the simulator. I can use `NSLog` to print the output to the debug screen but I'm at a loss to understand how to get the same output to the actual screen.

What I have now in `main.m`.

```
NSString *testvalue = @"Test";

NSLog(@"Output %@\n", testvalue);
```

My understanding is that all display operations occur in `viewcontroller.m` but from what I have been reading ,it seems that the action is not as simple as creating debug output.

Comment: Why are you using `Objective-C` instead of `Swift` ?...Swift is much more easier to understand in beginning...
Beginner Tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=09TeUXjzpKs

Comment: Thanks for responding Nayan! Could you give an example how in this case, Swift is easier? Post a comparison of how it would be done in both Swift and Objective-C. I've seen that video before but since I'm using Objective-C, it didn't seem relevant. Does that video also apply to Objective-C?

Comment: You can use a `UILabel` added as a subview to your `UIViewController`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour] and read [ask] and provide a [example] describing your question. And have a look at the Apple documentation to get you started: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/

Comment: This is not about which language is easier ... that said, you can use ```UILabel``` to display a string but out the box that is nothing like the console where you can log output continously. There is not really some UI control for that nor is it something you typically do in the UI, but if your application requires such a log you can build one in a number of ways, possibly even using a ```UILabel```.

Comment: Thank you skaak and Kamil! skaak, I appreciate the extra detail! I'll followup on using UILabel.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to put some sort of UI control on the screen with the capability of displaying text. UILabel would probably be the simplest. Then set the content of the label to the text you want to display.